# Apply conditional formatting to entire row in excel

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I'm a python beginner. 
I'm trying to set the same conditional formatting for all the excel files i have within a folder using pandas and xlsxwriter. 
The files are structured like this:

```
A    | B   | C   | ... | K
ID   | ... | ... | ... | Risk
1    | ... | ... | ... | High
2    | ... | ... | ... | Medium
3    | ... | ... | ... | High
4    | ... | ... | ... | Low
```

I would like to set the same format (for the entire row) according to the value in the column k `risk`.

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import os

#Set the input directory
myFolder = r"MyFolderPath"
os.chdir(myFolder)

#generate a list of excel files using the glob method
fileList = glob.glob("*.xlsx")

#for each element within the list apply the conditional formatting
for elem in fileList:
    df = pd.read_excel(elem)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(df)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'sheet_1')

    workbook = writer.book

    format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'red'})
    format2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'yellow'})

    worksheet = writer.sheets['sheet_1']

    worksheet.conditional_format('K2:K100', {'type': 'cell',
                                     'criteria': 'equal to',
                                     'value': '"high"',
                                     'format': format1})
    worksheet.conditional_format('K2:K100', {'type': 'cell',
                                      'criteria': 'equal to',
                                      'value': '"medium"',
                                      'format': format2})
    workbook.close

print ("Done")
```

I had no errors, but the script is not modifying the files.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the type to formula and the criteria to your desired condition. Check this example to see exactly how you should write it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4],
                    'B': ['a','b','c','d'],
                    'Risk': ["High","Medium","High","Low"]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format_red = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE'})
format_yellow = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFEB9C'})
format_green = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#C6EFCE'})

worksheet.conditional_format('A2:C5', {'type': 'formula',
                            'criteria': '=$C2="High"',
                            'format': format_red})

worksheet.conditional_format('A2:C5', {'type': 'formula',
                            'criteria': '=$C2="Medium"',
                            'format': format_yellow})

worksheet.conditional_format('A2:C5', {'type': 'formula',
                            'criteria': '=$C2="Low"',
                            'format': format_green})

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's very useful for me!
So if understood i can't read directly read a dataframe with xlsxwriter, but i have to read it with pandas and then write a new file with xlsxwriter, and populate it with dataframe i need, right?

Comment: Use both tools for what they are best at. Read your file with pandas and do all the data manipulation with it (the most powerful data analysis library), then if you want to format the file output it with xlsxwriter.

Comment: Ok, but i'm still looking for how to read my output file with xlsxwriter.
i'm trying with ```writer = pd.read_excel``` but then i have an AttributeError: ```DataFrame object has no attribute 'book'```

Comment: You can not read your file with xlsxwriter, you need either to create one from scratch (which is not useful) or pass one from pandas like in your example that you posted.